# Enable/disable the custom field when another custom field is selected

Tags: ruby

I need to disable one custom field when other custom field is selected. For example, I have an custom field with dropdown format. When i click on 2nd option of a particular custom field,the other custom field should be disabled and one more custom field should be enabled. How do i do that in `redmine`?

Comment: You can achieve this by Jquery. It will be better if you give some example or make it more clear in details

Comment: Ex:The first custom field is 'activity', and it has the options installation, training and others. If i select installation i would like to show another custom field called 'progress' and other list in that field. If Training is selected i would like to show a custom field called 'location' and another called 'trainer' and hide the 'progress' custom field.Please let me know how to do this.M using redmine with ruby on rails..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood you wanted to change the option of 2nd dropdown box on bases of 1st dropdown's option selection:

This is sample code which perform the same using Jquery. You can modify it as per your requirement.

**HTML**

```
<select class="product" id="select_1" name="product">
  <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Category </option>
  <option value="Mens Suits"> Mens Suits </option>
  <option value="Womens Suit"> Womens Suits </option>
  <option value="Children Suit"> Children Suits </option>
</select>

<select class="size" id="select_3" name="size">
  <option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option>
</select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
var men = '<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option><option value="36">36</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="40">40</option>';
var women = '<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option><option value="26">26</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="30">30</option>';
var children = '<option selected="selected" value=""> Choose Size </option><option value="12">12</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="10">10</option>';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#select_1").on('change',function(){
        if($(this).val()=="Mens Suits"){
            $("select#select_3").html(men);
        }else if($(this).val()=="Womens Suit"){
            $("select#select_3").html(women);
        }else if($(this).val()=="Children Suit"){
            $("select#select_3").html(children);
        }
    });
});
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaganGami/rTL9Y/251/)

I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thank you Sir,It would be very helpful if you  send me the code using ruby code..

Comment: are you using Ruby with rails framework?  Rails support Jquery, html so you can use this code simply in your app.

Comment: Sir,since I am new to it I dont know where I am suppoe to write the code..So could you please tell me?

Comment: As you are new, you need to first understand the basics. There are numbers of tutorials and guides are available. Refer this : http://guides.rubyonrails.org , https://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: What kind of questions?

Comment: In the above code i want to add another custom field..I.e when i select the "mens suit" from "choose category" i need to enable only tha field which contain mens size shirt..Please do help

Comment: All options contains different size.. Check the demo and change the selection it will change the options of 2nd dropdown as well

Comment: I have added three more custom field.How do i program it to enable/disable the other two custom field when i select "men shirts" from choose category?if i select mens shirt then only the custom field with mens size should be enabled..

Comment: Hello Sir,I Have modified the code and used in rails but m getting certain errors when i run that code..

Comment: @ruby: If you can't understand why that errors come then debug your code or copy the error and search for the solution. You can also post new question with sample code and error.